# Accesing elements in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, xml

I am very new in python. I am trying to acces data in a xml file.
my xml file and code is as below:

```
 import xmltodict

#from xml.dom import minidom

#doc = minidom.parse("staff.xml")



data = """<Azimuth>
      <COL_STEP unit="m">5000</COL_STEP>
      <ROW_STEP unit="m">5000</ROW_STEP>
      <Values_List>
        <VALUES>59.9563 53.0871 44.4595 33.8743 21.5482 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>58.4469 51.1869 42.099 31.0545 18.418 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>56.8537 49.1809 39.623 28.139 15.2538 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>55.1672 47.0649 37.0345 25.1409 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>53.3851 44.8373 34.3343 22.0718 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>51.5013 42.4952 31.5308 18.9484 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>49.5128 40.0378 28.6308 15.7878 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>47.4157 37.4668 25.6447 12.609 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>45.2056 34.7844 22.5855 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>42.8812 31.9968 19.4688 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>40.442 29.1107 16.3121 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>37.8884 26.1373 13.134 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>35.2231 23.0883 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>32.4513 19.9792 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>29.5804 16.8268 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>26.6194 13.6499 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>23.5805 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>20.479 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>17.3318 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>14.1568 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
        <VALUES>NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN</VALUES>
      </Values_List>
    </Azimuth>"""

data = xmltodict.parse(data, encoding='utf-8')
p=data['Azimuth']['Values_List']
print(type(p))

import dict_digger

print(dict_digger.dig(data, 'Values_List'))
```

What I am trying to acces the 23*23 array inside the 'Values List' but I am struggling. Is there any way I can acces those values?

Thanks

Comment: Keys in a dict must be unique, but all the elements inside `<Values_List>` are `<VALUES>` so you only have one dict item. I don't know how `xmltodict` handles that.

Comment: Also, I don't think `xmltodict` attempts to handle space-separated values like that (which is not the XML way). You could use Python `split` to break that into a list.

Comment: Is anyone familiar with that `dict_digger` module used here? Seems interesting / wild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
p=data['Azimuth']['Values_List']['VALUES']
```

You'll probably want the matrix as a `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np
parsedMatrix = np.array([line.split(' ') for line in p]).astype(float)
```

Comment: I have tried, but that gives me the array in which the values are actually space seperated. My concern is to acces those values and process them. Thanks.

Comment: See the second part of my answer that uses `split`.

Comment: That really helped, thanks a lot. Actually I am familiar with Matlab, but had no idea about Python. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer and good luck with Python. The `numpy`module  behaves quite similarly to Matlab. :-)